# How is a TLS certificate authenticated, down to a code level?

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, hash, certificate-authority

I am having trouble to understand how a TLS certificate is authenticated.

From what I read, a server's leaf certificate contains:

- Server domain name
- Server public key
- Issuer (CA) domain name
- Issuer (CA) signature of this certificate

How is the issuer signature of the certificate verified? Is it a hash function using the upper certificate's public key as an input? Like:

`childCertificateSignature = hash(childCertificate, upperCertificatePrivateKey)`

and to validate:

`isChildCertificateValid = isHashValid(childCertificateSignature, upperCertificatePublicKey)`

?

Comment: If you want to know down to a code level, why not read a reference implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL/TLS client authentication - practical client cert validation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89719/ssl-tls-client-authentication-practical-client-cert-validation). See also [How does browser actually verify...](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity).

Comment: As for "down to a code level" - I consider this way too broad since the code is complex. There are several open source implementations of SSL out there, so please study these.